# Solr - Assign dynamically different fieldType based on other filed value

Tags: solr

I am trying to index my fields with different stemming algorithms based on the language they are written.

So i have three fields: ID, Text and language (language can be "french", "german" or "english")

My documents could look like that:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">1</field>
    <field name="text">Etwas auf deutsch</field>
    <field name="lang">German</field>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">2</field>
    <field name="text">Something in english</field>
    <field name="lang">English</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

I have three fieldType in my schema => str_en, str_ger, str_fr and I want to change the fieldType for the field "text" based on the value in field "lang".

Does anybody know a way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you seen https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/detecting-languages-during-indexing.html ?

Comment: .. or since you already know the language going in - a regular update processor will work, for example a StatelessScript processor with a few if-statements. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/update-request-processors.html

Comment: Thank you for your input.

I've now completely changed my approach. I extract the data now into seperate fields named description_<language>. Makes my life easier.

Comment: Great, that sounds like a far easier solution when you have control over the input. :-)